# What is a universal video format(and video/audio streaming codification) for all Android Webview versions

Tags: android, video, encoding, webview, format

I have a web-view in an application and i use html5  tag.
I have had all kinds of issues on different android devices(samsung, sony, etc) with different android versions. Some could not play .mp4 and only played .m4v extensions. Another old tablet could only play mp4.
On an Xperia I had a special case. The webview couldn't play the video in html and played it in another custom video view(although this didn't bother me at all).

I need the videos to autoplay as soon as i open the webview(and have managed to do it on those few videos that work), and i have end-video event handlers that have to fire at the right time.

If anyone knows what video format + video and audio codification to use in order to have compatibility with all webviews on android please

Answer (score 1):

Android webview and HTML5 player that works with the video codecs that Android supports (.mp4 is best for progressive video as it has by far the widest support), and it also supports .flv with flash plugin.